# Get elements of specific hierarchy level

Tags: xpath

Is there any way to retrieve all elements of specific hierarchy level using XPath?

Upd.

```
<A>
   <B>1</B>
   <B>2</B>
</A>
<C>
   <D>3</D>
   <D>4</D>
</C>
```

I need to retrieve all B and D elements (hierarchy level = 2)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your example lacks a root element, so I assume something like this:

```
<ROOT>
  <A>
    <B>1</B>
    <B>2</B>
  </A>
  <C>
    <D>3</D>
    <D>4</D>
  </C>
</ROOT>
```

With this, a simple version would be to just use the appropriate number of 'any element' wildcards to get your result:

```
xpath = '/*/*/*'
```

(Meaning 'select any child element of any child element of any root element')

Alternatively, if you want to express the level numerically, you could use:

```
xpath = '//*[count(ancestor::*) = 2]'
```

(Meaning 'select any element with 2 ancestors')

---

**Edit/Note:** As Dimitre Novatchev correctly pointed out, it is important to differentiate between *nodes* and *elements*, and I fixed my answer accordingly. (While elements are nodes themselves, [there are also six other types of nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#data-model)!)

The difference can be illustrated with the given example by altering the ancestor based xpath slightly to:

```
xpath = '//*[count(ancestor::node())=2]'
```

**This would select A and B**, as the root element  would count as one ancestor node, and the root node '/' as another!

Comment: While this answer is correct, there are certain terminological issues. In XPath "node" is something generally different from "element". In particular, the `root node`, selected by the XPath expression `/` is *not* an element. Also, besides element children an element can have children of type: text node, comment and processing instruction. Please, correct the statements in your answer referring to "node" to refer to "element".

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: Oups, You're right, of course - thanks for pointing this out. I adjusted the answer accordingly (and added a demonstration of the difference as a bonus ;)

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: BTW, given your rep count, why not just fix errors like this yourself directly?

Comment: [why not just fix errors like this yourself directly?] Because I only have time to downvote ... :) In this case this was a minor issue in your answer, so a downvote would be unfair.

Now you have a +1 from me.